# What am I missing to get a PHP ScriptEngine in Java

Tags: java, php

I try to get a PHP ScriptEngine from the ScriptEngineManager, but getEngineByName("php") returns null. The following unit test works, if I replace "php" with "javascript", but it fails for "php".

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import javax.script.*;

public class ScriptEngineTest {
    @Test
    public void executeCommand() throws Exception {
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("php");
        assertNotNull(engine);
    }
}
```

I must be missing something obvious. I know, that Rhino comes with Java 6 and is behind the javascript engine. Where do I get this for PHP?

### EDIT:

I made my first step forward. [Here](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/installation.php)is a download link for JavaBridgeTemplate5442.war. I unzipped this war file. Under WEB-INF/lib/ I found the jar files

- JavaBridge.jar
- php-script.jar
- php-servlet.jar

When I put JavaBridge.jar in my class path, the unit test works. (Probably I will also need php-script.jar to actually execute PHP code.)

Answer (score 1):

Scripting engines available under JSR 223 are listed [here](https://scripting.dev.java.net/) (bottom of the page).

Current implementations of PHP include [Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/) and [PHP to Java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/).

Comment: I saw both before, but for Quercus still I do not see, how I can integrate it. I finally made it with php-java-bridge. I will edit my question.

Comment: Look here: http://groovy-news.org/e/page/axelclk?entry=experiments_with_the_jsr_223
and here: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ludo/archive/2007/03/100_java_quercu.html

I haven't tried Quercus myself, though.

Comment: Thanks, looks similar to the solution I found for php-java-bridge. I think, that this packaging makes it a little harder to actually use these bridges.